# Allow content to be share in an iframes SharePoint 2019

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

Hello I manage 2 site Domain1.com is on SharePoint 2019 (on Prem) and I want to be able to show the content of Domain1.com in a iFrame on Domain2.com. When I currently do this I get an "iframe refused to connect." Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered

Can anyone tell me what changes I need to do on the Share Point site to allow Domain2.com to display the data. I am NOT looking to make the content available to any domain, just domain2.com

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add domain 1 (SharePoint site 1) URL in `iframe` on SharePoint site pages (on domain 2), try adding domain 1 URL in HTML Field Security Settings on domain 2 SharePoint site.

You can find these settings at: **Site Settings** > **HTML Field Security**

[image]

**References**:

1. [SharePoint: External Image URLs not working in JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/08/27/sharepoint-online-external-image-urls-not-working-in-json-formatting/)
2. [Allow or restrict the ability to embed content on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/allow-or-restrict-the-ability-to-embed-content-on-sharepoint-pages-e7baf83f-09d0-4bd1-9058-4aa483ee137b)

Comment: The problem here is that Domain2 is not a sharepoint site. I want to be able to show some of the sharepoint content from Domain1 (sharepoint) on the non-sharepoint site domain2